# PHP Ratings - Dynamically populate a page with all rated items in database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database, sqlite

for a few years I have been using a simple cpanel built in php ratings system.
Does anyone know if it is possible to dynamically populate a php page with all rated items in database.? and If so, what the best way to achieve this?

My main goal is to read all rated items from database & order them from highest rated to lowest rated.

the php ratings consists of 5 files. 
ratings.php   ratings.css   ratings.js   ratings.gif  and ratings.sqlite

I will provide code(s) below.

ratings.php

```
<?php
class rating{

public $average = 0;
public $votes;
public $status;
public $table;
private $path;

function __construct($table){
    try{
        $pathinfo = pathinfo(__FILE__);
        $this->path = realpath($pathinfo['dirname']) .     "/database/ratings.sqlite";
        $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:$this->path");
        $this->table = $dbh->quote($table);
        // check if table needs to be created
        $table_check = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE    id='1'");
        if(!$table_check){
            // create database table
            $dbh->query("CREATE TABLE $this->table (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,    rating FLOAT(3,2), ip VARCHAR(15))");
            $dbh->query("INSERT INTO $this->table (rating, ip) VALUES (0,   'master')");                
        } else {
            $this->average = $table_check->fetchColumn(1);
        }
        $this->votes = ($dbh->query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $this->table")-  >fetchColumn()-1);
    }catch( PDOException $exception ){
            die($exception->getMessage());
    }
    $dbh = NULL;        
}

function set_score($score, $ip){
    try{
        $dbh = new PDO("sqlite:$this->path");
        $voted = $dbh->query("SELECT id FROM $this->table WHERE ip='$ip'");
        if(sizeof($voted->fetchAll())==0){

            $dbh->query("INSERT INTO $this->table (rating, ip) VALUES    ($score, '$ip')");
            $this->votes++;

            //cache average in the master row
            $statement = $dbh->query("SELECT rating FROM $this->table");
            $total = $quantity = 0;
            $row = $statement->fetch(); //skip the master row
            while($row = $statement->fetch()){
                $total = $total + $row[0];
                $quantity++;
            }
            $this->average = round((($total*20)/$quantity),0);
            $statement = $dbh->query("UPDATE $this->table SET rating =   $this->average WHERE id=1");
            $this->status = '(thanks!)';
        } else {
            $this->status = '(already scored)';
        }

    }catch( PDOException $exception ){
            die($exception->getMessage());
    }
    $dbh = NULL;
}
}

function rating_form($table){
$ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
if(!isset($table) && isset($_GET['table'])){
    $table = $_GET['table'];
}
$rating = new rating($table);
$status = "<div class='score'>
            <a class='score1' href='?    score=1&amp;table=$table&amp;user=$ip'>1</a>
            <a class='score2' href='?score=2&amp;table=$table&amp;user=$ip'>2</a>
            <a class='score3' href='?score=3&amp;table=$table&amp;user=$ip'>3</a>
            <a class='score4' href='?score=4&amp;table=$table&amp;user=$ip'>4</a>
            <a class='score5' href='?score=5&amp;table=$table&amp;user=$ip'>5</a>
        </div>
";
if(isset($_GET['score'])){
    $score = $_GET['score'];
    if(is_numeric($score) && $score <=5 && $score >=1 &&   ($table==$_GET['table']) && isset($_GET["user"]) && $ip==$_GET["user"]){
        $rating->set_score($score, $ip);
        $status = $rating->status;
    }
}
if(!isset($_GET['update'])){ echo "<div class='rating_wrapper'>"; }
?>
<div class="sp_rating">
    <div class="rating">Rating:</div>
    <div class="base"><div class="average" style="width:<?php echo $rating-      >average; ?>%"><?php echo $rating->average; ?></div></div>
    <div class="votes"><?php echo $rating->votes; ?> votes</div>
    <div class="status">
        <?php echo $status; ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['update'])){ echo "</div>"; }
}

if(isset($_GET['update'])&&isset($_GET['table'])){
rating_form($_GET['table']);
}
```

ratings.css

```
.rating_wrapper *{margin:0; border:0; padding:0;}
.rating_wrapper {overflow:hidden; height:16px;}
.sp_rating{font-family:Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-    size:11px; line-height:1.7em; color:#5f5f5f; display:block;}
.rating{float:left; padding-right:4px;}
.base{background:url(ratings.gif) 0 0 no-repeat; width:85px; height:100%;      float:left; padding-right:4px; overflow:hidden;}
.average{background:url(ratings.gif) 0 -16px no-repeat; text-indent:-9999px;}
.votes{float:left; padding-right:4px;}
.score{ background:url(ratings.gif) 0 0 no-repeat; width:85px; height:100%;   float:left; position:relative;}
    .score a{display:block; height:100%; float:left; text-indent:-9999px;  position:absolute; overflow:hidden; line-height:1em;}
    .score1 {width:20%; z-index:55;}
    .score2 {width:40%; z-index:54;}
    .score3 {width:60%; z-index:53;}
    .score4 {width:80%; z-index:52;}
    .score5 {width:100%; z-index:51;}
    .score a:hover{ background:url(ratings.gif) bottom right no-repeat;}
.status {height:16px; width:100px; overflow:hidden; position:relative;}

.score_this{ height:100%; overflow:hidden;}
    .score_this a{color:#f37800;}
```

ratings.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.status').prepend("<div class='score_this'>(<a href='#'>Rate Artist</a>)    </div>");
$('.score_this').click(function(){
    $(this).slideUp();
    return false;
});

$('.score a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().parent().addClass('scored');
    $.get("rating/rating.php" + $(this).attr("href") +"&update=true", {},   function(data){
        $('.scored').fadeOut("normal",function() {
            $(this).html(data);
            $(this).fadeIn();
            $(this).removeClass('scored');
        });
    });
    return false; 
});
});
```

Thank you in advance, any and all help is appreciated.

Comment: How would you achieve this? By querying table form jQuery and then inserting returned table somewhere into existing DOM?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like all you need to do is use a where conditional on your database (assuming the ratings are stored there). If they are not stored there, you may have to fetch it from the cookie or wherever else it is stored.

```
 SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE rating > 0
```

Once you have the returned results from that query, use PHP sort methods like asort to order the results how you'd like (highest to lowest, lowest to highest). Printing or echoing this out will give you the effect you want, ratings in a particular order.

Alternatively, you could add in an ORDER BY condition to your query, like ORDER BY rating DESC or ASC (descending and ascending respectively).

```
  SELECT * FROM table WHERE rating > 0 ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Comment: I think the SQL should be "FROM table", but that's just a detail.